# UIButton image automatically resizes even with constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, nslayoutconstraint

I have a minor issue, which I am probably not able to get my head around. I have a uibutton added programmatically. To that button I am adding a UIImage. I am just adding basic constraints, but for some reason it tends to shrink to a smaller size while running on screen.

Following is the code I have for generating the button:

```
var shareButton: UIButton!

    func addShareButton() {
        shareButton = UIButton()
        shareButton.autoresizesSubviews = false
        shareButton.clipsToBounds = true
        shareButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        shareButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
        shareButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "wshare"), for: .normal)
        shareButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(shareButtonPressed), for: .touchDown)
        shareButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(shareButtonReleased), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(shareButton)
    }

    func addConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // Share Button
            shareButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            shareButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            shareButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -15),
            shareButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -25),
            ])
    }

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        addConstraints()
        super.updateViewConstraints()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        addShareButton()
    }
```

And what it generates is this: 
[image]

The bigger box is supposed to be the actual size which is 60x60, but it magically shrinks to 32x32.

Can you help me point the issue. I know I am missing something quite silly, But I am not able get my head around it.

Comment: If I'ma be honest, I have NEVER, not one time, had an easy time with the method `setImage`. Personally, I'd create a `UIImageView` an simply add the imageView as a subview to the button. From there, you can customize the imageView as you please.

Comment: Well, that's my last catch. I was just hoping, I could have this straight before taking that option. Well, I guess I am not left with much

Comment: For the sake of having an accepted answer, I'll post my answer and you can decide whether or not you want to.

Comment: Haha. I was about to delete this, since the question held not much of a value. Do it. I’ll accept;)

Comment: I had a question I thought I'd delete, it has now 12 upvotes and my own answer has 10. I was surprised nonetheless. It's simply about multiple gestures.

Comment: Thats why i said do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I like to keep my objects separate. While `UIButton` has a `setImage(:UIImage)` method, I prefer to create a `UIButton` then add my own `UIImageView` to it then add my own `UIImage`. So, in hierachy

```
-- UIButton
    -- UIImageView
        -- UIImage
```

With this, you can specify the specific bounds and any other variables associated to `UIImageView`. I find this methodology to be incredibly more concrete, especially if you have to alter the `UIImageView`.